# Where does Cabal search for files listed in "includes: ..."?

Tags: haskell, cabal

The [Cabal documentation](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-includes) has this to say on the `includes` attribute:

> **includes**: *filename list*
>
> A list of header files to be included in any compilations via C. This field applies to both header files that are already installed on the system and to those coming with the package to be installed. The former files should be found in absolute paths, while the latter files should be found in paths relative to the top of the source tree or relative to one of the directories listed in `include-dirs`.
>
> These files typically contain function prototypes for foreign imports used by the package.

I find the statement "The former files should be found in absolute paths" to be unhelpfully vague; how do I find out specifically *which* absolute paths Cabal will look in, so that I can ensure that I am putting necessary files in a place where they can "be found"?

Comment: I suspect it doesn't do *anything* smart at all. "Should be found in absolute paths" likely means it's on you, the cabal-file writer, to put the correct absolute path in the list. ...but this is conjecture based on a slightly different reading of the text than yours, not based on any expertise I have in cabal, so I relegate it to a comment rather than an answer...

Comment: @DanielWagner Are you saying it means that the entries in the `includes` list should themselves *be* absolute paths?

Comment: Translated, I think it means that the files should be given either as absolute paths or as paths relative to the top of the source tree or as paths relative to an include-dir.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Yes, that is how I read it.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think you should submit your comment as an answer